# Sum Distinct in one sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, qsqlquery

## I am really confused,i was trying and searching for couple days with no results, please kindly help me, i have table like this

```
barcode  pname      psize      quantity  orderno
1       test1      Small         10       15
1       test1      XSmall        2        16
1       test1      XSmall        6        17
1       test1      Large         12       18
1       test1      xlarge        1        19
1       test1      Small         17       20
1       test1      large         9        21
2       test2      Small         9        22
2       test2      Small         9        23
```

=======
i want to sum each size for each barcode (for example i want the sum of small size for the barcode 1) so the result would be like

```
barcode  pname      psize      quantity  
1       test1      Small         27          
1       test1      XSmall        8       
1       test1      Large         21      
1       test1      xlarge        1            
2       test2      Small         18
```

i've tried the folowing sql query:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) AS quantity
      FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT barcode, quantity,psize FROM products )
```

but the result gives me (75) which is the sub total.
any help please. i am using vb.net 2008 with sql 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT barcode, pname, psize, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM products 
GROUP BY barcode, pname, psize
```

Comment: thank u so much, it worked finally, thanks, i will accept the answer